# How to SELECT the max number base on another attribute's value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 3 columns, which is "year", "students_count" and "faculty".
And I want to find out what is the biggest number of "students_count" for each different faculty.

The table looks like this:

```
year| students_count| faculty
------------------------------------
2001| 50            | Business
2002| 60            | Business
2003| 40            | Business
2001| 20            | Engineering
2002| 10            | Engineering
2003| 50            | Law
```

```
SELECT year,max(students_count),faculty FROM table;
```

(it doesn't work)

```
year| students_count| faculty
-----------------------------------
2002| 60            | Business
2001| 20            | Engineering
2003| 50            | Law
```

Comment: You have to group by the fields of each group to summarize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need group by if you need per year and faculty wise maximum

```
SELECT year,max(students_count),faculty FROM table group by year,faculty
```

but if you need only faculty wise then you could use corelated subquery

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from table_name t
order by row_number() over (partition by faculty order by students_count   desc)
```

Answer (score 1):

use `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by faculty order by students_count desc) as rn
from tablename 
)A where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `dense_rank()` :

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             dense_Rank() over (partition by faculty order by students_count desc) as seq
      from table t
     ) t
where seq = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

this will do:

```
select * from (select *,rank() over (partition by faculty order by sytudents_count desc 
) rnk form tablename) where rnk=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

For this I think you just need to use group by in your sql.
This maybe solve that problem.

```
Create Table School(
Year Number(4),
Students_Count Number(2),
Faculty Varchar2(20)
);

Insert Into School  Values (2001,50,'Business');
Insert Into School  Values (2002,60,'Business');
Insert Into School  Values (2003,40,'Business');
Insert Into School  Values (2001,20,'Engineering');
Insert Into School  Values (2002,10,'Engineering');
Insert Into School  Values (2003,50,'Law');

Select * From School;

Select  Faculty,Max(Students_Count) From School
Group By Faculty;
```